# Strange behavior for files in /app/webroot when using ajax

Tags: ajax, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

In my cakePHP v2.* I had a completely working application that does an ajax post to a file in `/app/webroot/lib/upload/process.php`

I now moved the site to a new server and get a missing controller error when I do the ajax post to the same file. So my first thought would be that somehow `mod_rewrite` wasn't configured... But the strangest thing is, when I access the file from my browser no error is shown. So only with the ajax call

BTW. I am running the site on an Ubuntu 14.04 server using ISPConfig as management console

The error I get is:

```
Missing Controller
Error: LibController could not be found.
Error: Create the class LibController below in file: app/Controller/LibController.php
```

And the ajax script is:

```
$('#my-upload-form').submit(function() {
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
    return false;
});
```

Where the form is:

```
<form action="/lib/upload/process.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="my-upload-form">
```

Console:

```
Request URL:https://www.bukadoo.com/lib/upload/process.php
Request Method:POST
Status Code:404 Not Found
Remote Address:52.37.22.4:443
```

The .htaccess in the root:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

The .htaccess in `webroot` folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Can you post the exact error you are getting and perhaps a screenshot of the Ajax Request (using Browser's Developer Tools)?

Comment: I just added those to the question

Comment: I would suggest you review your `.htaccess` files. Depending on how you uploaded your content to the new server, those might not have been uploaded. Especially the one off `webroot` folder

Comment: Is just added both htaccess files to the question. Do you see anything wrong there?

Answer (score 0):

Well in the end it was a server issue. After installing the application on a whole different server things were working fine.

After a long search I found out that I needed to set the settings in ISPConfig from `Fast-CGI` to `Mod-PHP`